# validates_presence_of only sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have User and Client, both of which have one Address. I want to make address.street required only for Client. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is put the condition right into the validation. Take a look at the [rails_doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :street, :presence => true, :unless => 'client.nil?'

end
```

Answer (score 2):

you could write your own custom validation, something like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :client_street_required

  def client_street_required
    if self.street.blank? and !self.Client.blank?
      errors.add(:street, "required")
    end
  end

end
```